# Xamarin Forms Error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected (Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

I'm trying to use Google Ads with the package `MarcTron.AdMob`.

After I install it, I need to install some dependencies and update some packages, as it said me to do:

```
Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser
Xamarin.Google.Android.Material
Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData
Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4
```

But after I install/update all this dependencies, I compile again and get the error:

```
2>myproject.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\111\jl\res\values\values.xml(1482): error APT1000: Attribute "android:translationX" has already been defined
2>myproject.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\111\jl\res\values\values.xml(1486): error APT1000: Attribute "android:translationY" has already been defined
2>myproject.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\111\jl\res\values\values.xml(1489): error APT1000: Attribute "android:translationZ" has already been defined
2>myproject.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\83\jl\res\values\values.xml(4): error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
2>myproject.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\82\jl\res\values\values.xml(4): error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
2>myproject.Android\obj\Debug\100\lp\76\jl\res\values\values.xml(4): error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
```

What I already did:

- Cleaned the project and compiled it again;
- Follow this solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91bce7cf-16f5-4037-902b-93309bb5d448/error-apt1000-found-tag-id-where-item-is-expected-apt1000-swlogandroid?forum=xamarinforms);
- Removed the whitespaces of `colors.xml` and `styles.xml` inside my Resources (it was another solution that I saw);
- Change the API level (28 - 9.0 and 29 - 10.0).
- Downgrade the packages.

Nothing worked.

I tried to using `Xamarin.Firebase.Ads` instead of `MarcTron.AdsMob` but the same error appears to me.

What is this error and how can I solve it? I really need to put ads on the application and I can't continue the project with this error.

Comment: have you examined the `values.xml` for the reported errors?

Comment: Yes, it is on my debug folder. I opened, the lines: `<attr format="dimension" name="android:translationX"/>`. All of them is in this way, just changing the name `translationY` and `translationZ`. It says that has already been defined, but I can't find "the other place" to I change, everything is on Debug, if I edit, clean and rebuild, all the modification will disappear.

Comment: delete the tag, and re-write it by hand (DON'T COPY/PASTE).

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I understand what you're saying, but do you agree with me that this folder is "Debug", and if I clean the project, everything that I re-write will lost?! And even if I only recompile?! I tested creating a blank project and put this package and it compiles. I will try using Shell because I use in the project that is sending me the error and finally copy the files of my current project to this blank project, I can't see other solution. I'll update this question when I finish it.

Comment: Did u ever find a solution am encounting the exact same issue ?

Comment: @csharpdude77 yes, look the accepted answer. My folder or project had some letter with accent, for example, "ó".

Comment: I am having same issue but i dont have any weird phrases in my folder names just a full stop as standard for example APPName.Andriod AppName.Ios @AdrainZhu-MSFT why u telling people to type something out by hand that is autogenerated by the compiler ! ms needs to fixs its tooling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was creating a blank project and copy/paste all my classes, folders, resources...

I really wanted to solve this because in several sites has the same question that I did, so it was good to help the community. For now, the solution was that.

EDIT:

All right ladies and gentlemen, I found the BIZARRE error of this: Just my folder that I have the folder of my project has an accent: "ó". Just that.

Answer (score 11):

In my case checking "Use incremental Android packaging system (aapt2)" in Android options in project Properties fixed the issue.

Comment: Same here, i just tried to Uncheck "Use incremental Android packaging system (aapt2)" - in order to try have a clean copy installed everytime i debug - for sanity purposes and also for testing stability thinking this would help to have a fresh packaging system install each time - but then these errors appeared straight away. 

Checking it again, resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I dont think that solves the issue incremntal is only to be used whe they have the app already on their device is it not ?

Comment: It makes me angry this worked. God, VS sucks on Mac...

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue when using Migrate to AndroidX. What I did to fix it was I checked and saw that some of the Android Nuget packages didn't migrate over to AndroidX. So you may be missing some AndroidX Nuget Packages. Add some of them and see if it builds.

Comment: Nope, I installed, hm, about 20 AndroidX packages and nothing worked.